# Access Ignite java cache using Ignite c++ client

Tags: java, c++, ignite

I have a java server running on one system and its load data from database and cached to Java cache. I have other C++ client which is running using the same configuration of java. Both are running on different PC.  I want to use a common cache for both java & c++ client means if i am loading cache using java and after that i want to query this cache data through my c++ client. I just take a try by setting the multicast option like this.

```
   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
        <property name="multicastGroup" value="228.10.10.157"/>
```

If both the client are working on same system its works good. But when both the are in different PC its not identify each other and it works like two different cache

Comment: What is the issue? Can you share exception stack trace or any details on how exactly it does not work?

Comment: @isapego I have edited my question please take a look

Comment: I have seen when multicast does not work by reason of network configuration. Why do not you use TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder?
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#section-static-ip-based-discovery

Answer (score 0):

Most likely multicast is disabled, not configured properly or blocked by firewalls in your network. Try to use static IP finder configuration and check if it works: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#section-static-ip-based-discovery